# linqとsqlの結果を同じにしたい

Tags: c#, linq

お世話になっております。以前に質問させていただいた内容と被るのですが、解決できていない箇所があるので再度投稿させて頂きます。
SQLと同じ結果を出したいのですが、linqでleftjoinした際に違う結果になります。
いろいろと調べてlinqを書いてみたのですが、なかなかうまく行きません。
どなたかご指摘いただけますでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

### テーブル定義

```
TMP1
    ID         int
    START_DATE datetime
    TOUROKU_NO int
    CD         string
```

### SQL

```
SELECT
BB1.*,
CASE WHEN BB2.START_DATE  is NULL THEN GETDATE() ELSE BB2.START_DATE  END AS END_DATE
FROM TMP1 AS BB1
LEFT JOIN TMP1 AS BB2 ON (BB1.ID = BB2.ID AND BB1.TOUROKU_NO = BB2.TOUROKU_NO AND BB1.START_DATE  < BB2.START_DATE
```

### SQL結果

```
ID 　　STARTDATE               TOROKU_NO   　　　CD 　　　　　  END_DATE       

7   2010-06-30 00:00:00.000　　 1           03010,                          2011-07-05 00:00:00.000
7   2010-06-30 00:00:00.000  　 1           03010,                          2011-09-26 00:00:00.000
7   2010-06-30 00:00:00.000 　　1         　 03010,                          2011-12-06 00:00:00.000
7   2010-06-30 00:00:00.000　　 2           02010,                          2011-12-06 00:00:00.000
7   2010-06-30 00:00:00.000　　 3           10010,                          2016-11-01 14:48:08.410
7   2010-06-30 00:00:00.000 　　4           04441,                          2016-11-01 14:48:08.410
7   2011-07-05 00:00:00.000 　　1           09010,                          2011-09-26 00:00:00.000
7   2011-07-05 00:00:00.000 　　1           09010,                          2011-12-06 00:00:00.000
7   2011-09-26 00:00:00.000 　　1           10010,                          2011-12-06 00:00:00.000
7   2011-12-06 00:00:00.000　　 1         　 09010,                          2016-11-01 14:48:08.410
7   2011-12-06 00:00:00.000 　　2           04441,                          2016-11-01 14:48:08.410
```

### LINQ

```
var result =
            from orig in TMP1
             join alias in TMP1
             on orig.ID equals alias.ID into g
             from alias in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where orig.TOUROKU_NO == alias.TOUROKU_NO && orig.START_DATE < alias.START_DATE 
             select new {
                 orig.ID,
                 orig.START_DATE ,
                 orig.TOUROKU_NO,
                 orig.CD,
                 END_DATE = (DBNull.Value.Equals(alias.START_DATE) ? (DateTime)orig.SERVERDATE : (DateTime)alias.START_DATE),
             };
```

### LINQ結果

```
ID 　　STARTDATE               TOROKU_NO   　　　CD 　　　　　  END_DATE       
7   2010/06/30 0:00:00  　　　　1   　　　　　　　03010,   　　2011/07/05 0:00:00
7   2010/06/30 0:00:00  　　　　1   　　　　　　　03010,   　　2011/09/26 0:00:00
7   2010/06/30 0:00:00  　　　　1   　　　　　　　03010,   　　2011/12/06 0:00:00
7   2010/06/30 0:00:00  　　　　2   　　　　　　　02010,   　　2011/12/06 0:00:00
7   2011/07/05 0:00:00  　　　　1   　　　　　　　09010,   　　2011/09/26 0:00:00
7   2011/07/05 0:00:00  　　　　1   　　　　　　　09010,   　　2011/12/06 0:00:00
7   2011/09/26 0:00:00  　　　　1   　　　　　　　10010,   　　2011/12/06 0:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pgrhoさん、@sayuriさん、回答ありがとうございます。
ご連絡が遅れまして、申し訳ないです。
先の質問ですが、自己結合を２回行う事によって解決しました。

### LINQ

```
    var result1 =
        from orig in TMP1
        join alias in TMP1
        on new { orig.ID, orig.TOUROKU_NO } equals new { alias.ID, alias.TOUROKU_NO } into g
        from alias in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where alias == null || orig.START_DATE < alias.START_DATE 
        select new {
            orig.ID,
            orig.START_DATE,
            orig.TOUROKU_NO,
            orig.CD,
            END_DATE = (alias.START_DATE == DateTime.MinValue ? (DateTime)orig.SERVERDATE : (DateTime)alias.START_DATE ),
        };

    //もう一度、自己結合
    var result =
        from orig in TMP1
        join alias in result1 
        on new { orig.ID, orig.START_DATE, orig.TOUROKU_NO } equals new { alias.ID, alias.START_DATE, alias.TOUROKU_NO } into g
        from alias in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new {
            orig.ID,
            orig.START_DATE,
            orig.TOUROKU_NO,
            orig.CD,
            END_DATE = ((alias == null) ? (DateTime)orig.SERVERDATE : (DateTime)alias.END_DATE),
        };
```

このlinqで試したところ、nullを考慮したうえで、SQLと同等の結果を出す事が出来ました。

Answer (score 1):

まずID同士を結合していますが、これが主キー扱いになっている場合は結合されるレコードが全く同一になるため結合自体が無視されます。

上記をクリアしたうえで外部結合にならないのは`where`で`alias`が`null`の場合を考慮していないためです。

```
where alias == null
   || (orig.TOUROKU_NO == alias.TOUROKU_NO
    && orig.START_DATE < alias.START_DATE)
```

### 追記

コメントで触れたログの取り方ですが、コンテキストの`Database`プロパティには`Log`というプロパティがあるので、例えば

```
using (var db = new TesDbContext())
{
    db.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
}
```

のように`string`を引数にとるメソッドを設定すれば`SQL`等のログが出力されます。質問の場合`db`の部分はおそらく`this`になると思います。

`Database.Log`を指定したうえで以下のクエリーを実行すると下記のログが出力されます。

```
var q = from orig in TMP1
        join alias in TMP1 on orig.ID equals alias.ID into g
        from alias in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where alias == null || (alias.TOUROKU_NO == orig.TOUROKU_NO && orig.START_DATE < alias.START_DATE)
        select new
        {
            orig.ID,
            orig.START_DATE,
            orig.TOUROKU_NO,
            orig.CD,
            END_DATE = (DateTime?)alias.START_DATE ?? DateTime.Now
        };
foreach (var e in q) ;
```

#### ログ

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID],
    [Extent1].[START_DATE] AS [START_DATE],
    [Extent1].[TOUROKU_NO] AS [TOUROKU_NO],
    [Extent1].[CD] AS [CD],
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[START_DATE] IS NULL) THEN SysDateTime() ELSE  CAST( [Extent2].[START_DATE] AS datetime2) END AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[E] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[E] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[ID]
    WHERE ([Extent2].[Key] IS NULL) OR (([Extent2].[TOUROKU_NO] = [Extent1].[TOUROKU_NO]) AND ([Extent1].[START_DATE] < [Extent2].[START_DATE]))
```

※[Key]は仮に付加した主キー列です。

このように`LEFT OUTER JOIN`自体は問題なく行われているので、後は`where`及び`END_DATE`の内容を想定データに合わせて修正すれば仕様は満たせるはずです。

ちなみにsayuriさんの方法だと

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID],
    [Extent1].[START_DATE] AS [START_DATE],
    [Extent1].[TOUROKU_NO] AS [TOUROKU_NO],
    [Extent1].[CD] AS [CD],
    [UnionAll1].[START_DATE] AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[E] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT
        [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID],
        [Extent2].[TOUROKU_NO] AS [TOUROKU_NO],
        [Extent2].[START_DATE] AS [START_DATE]
        FROM [dbo].[E] AS [Extent2]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT
        [Distinct1].[ID] AS [ID],
        [Distinct1].[TOUROKU_NO] AS [TOUROKU_NO],
        SysDateTime() AS [C1]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT
            [Extent3].[ID] AS [ID],
            [Extent3].[TOUROKU_NO] AS [TOUROKU_NO]
            FROM [dbo].[E] AS [Extent3]
        )  AS [Distinct1]) AS [UnionAll1] ON ([Extent1].[ID] = [UnionAll1].[ID]) AND ([Extent1].[TOUROKU_NO] = [UnionAll1].[TOUROKU_NO])
    WHERE [Extent1].[START_DATE] < [UnionAll1].[START_DATE]
```

このようなSQLが生成されてしまうので避けた方が良いです。

Comment: @pgrhoさんの式を試してみましたが、できませんでした。質問ですが、TMP1のID7は8行あり、どの行もstartDateにはnullは入っていません。SQLでleftjoinで自己結合するとstartDateにnullが入ってるように思えます。SQL結果の登録番号3、4の行と最後の2行のendTimeがGETDATE()で取得した時間になっています。（2016-11-01 14:48:08.410）これは結合したテーブルBB2 のstartDateがnullだからという事だと思っています。同じテーブルをleftjoinさせる際にStatTimeにnullは発生するのでしょうか？

Comment: @BAKZ `LEFT OUTER JOIN`なので右(2番目)のテーブルの列はすべて`NULL`となる可能性があります。

Comment: @BAKZ とりあえず取得結果ではなくSQL自体を検証することをお勧めします。SQLはVisual Studioのウォッチや`Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;`などで確認できます。

Comment: @pgrhoさん回答ありがとうございます。left outer joinだとnullになる可能性があるんですね。知りませんでした。SQL自体の検証というのは、動きという事でしょうか？SQLは現行の仕様なので変更はできないです。

Comment: @pgrho さん、私としては想定通りのSQLですが、「避けた方が良い」理由を教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: @sayuri コード及び実行計画が複雑になるからです。

Comment: まず @pgrho さんのコードですと`LEFT OUTER JOIN`の結合条件が変更されていてひとまず結合してから`WHERE`句で絞り込むようになっています。これでは`LEFT OUTER JOIN`によって適切な`NULL`行が生成されないように思うのですが。また質問は正規化されていないテーブルのように見受けられるので勝手に主キーを足すわけにもいかないと思います。という前提に立った時に、私のコードで生成されたSQLの実行計画は複雑と言えるのでしょうか？ 自分では`INNER JOIN`と`UNION ALL`ぐらいしかされておらず素直なSQLだと思うのですが…`GROUP BY`すら`DISTINCT`に最適化されてしまった。

Comment: @sayuri 左と右のレコードは十分に取得されており、右の`NULL`は必要であれば`END_DATE`の条件で制御できます。またKeyは定義しないとIDが暗黙の主キーとなり、最適化が発生するため仮に定義しているので特にクエリーの内容とは関係ありません。また私の元コメントの趣旨は「改修前のSQLとLINQクエリの比較検証」であることも付け加えておきます。

Comment: @pgrho さんのコードは`SELECT * FROM TMP1 AS BB1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TMP1 AS BB2 ON BB1.ID=BB2.ID`という自己結合からの絞り込みになるため右側に`NULL`が生成されることはないのではと指摘しているのですが？ そして元質問も`NULL`行が生成されない点を修正する質問では？ 改修前のSQLについては「LINQでは不等号での結合はサポートされません」という記述しましたが、比較対象にはならないと考えています。

Answer (score 0):

ID & TOROKU_NOごとに着目して、START_DATEに

```
START_DATE
2016/11/01
2016/11/02
2016/11/03
2016/11/04
2016/11/05
2016/11/06
2016/11/07
```

と7行存在していた場合は

```
START_DATE  END_DATE
2016/11/01  2016/11/02
2016/11/01  2016/11/03
2016/11/01  2016/11/04
2016/11/01  2016/11/05
2016/11/01  2016/11/06
2016/11/01  2016/11/07
2016/11/02  2016/11/03
2016/11/02  2016/11/04
2016/11/02  2016/11/05
2016/11/02  2016/11/06
2016/11/02  2016/11/07
2016/11/03  2016/11/04
2016/11/03  2016/11/05
2016/11/03  2016/11/06
2016/11/03  2016/11/07
2016/11/04  2016/11/05
2016/11/04  2016/11/06
2016/11/04  2016/11/07
2016/11/05  2016/11/06
2016/11/05  2016/11/07
2016/11/06  2016/11/07
2016/11/07  GETDATE()    // LEFT JOINでNULL行となった部分
```

と22行の結果を求めているのでしょうか？ このパターンはO(n^2)で結果行が増殖します。DBが結果行を用意するコスト、DB→アプリケーション間の通信コスト、アプリケーションでの受信コストが膨大になるためアプリケーション側で行生成することをお勧めします。

---

以下、誤りがあったので書き直しました。

> SQLと同じ結果を出したいのですが、linqでleftjoinした際に違う結果になります。

[LINQのjoin句は非等結合をサポートしていません](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb311040.aspx#%E9%9D%9E%E7%AD%89%E7%B5%90%E5%90%88)。そのため

```
LEFT JOIN TMP1 AS BB2
ON (BB1.ID = BB2.ID
    AND BB1.TOUROKU_NO = BB2.TOUROKU_NO
    AND BB1.START_DATE  < BB2.START_DATE
```

の`BB1.START_DATE < BB2.START_DATE`をそもそも表現できません。LINQで表現するためにはまず同等の結果となる別のSQLを組み立てる必要があります。

```
-- LEFT JOINのうち結合に成功する部分
SELECT s.ID, s.START_DATE, s.TOUROKU_NO, s.CD, e.START_DATE AS END_DATE
FROM TMP1 AS s, TMP1 AS e
WHERE s.ID=e.ID AND s.TOUROKU_NO=e.TOUROKU_NO AND s.START_DATE < e.START_DATE

UNION ALL

-- LEFT JOINのうち結合に成功せずNULLが挿入される部分
-- BB1.START_DATE < BB2.START_DATEが成立しない、つまりBB1.START_DATEが最大値となるもの
SELECT t.ID, t.START_DATE, t.TOUROKU_NO, t.CD, GETDATE()
FROM (
    SELECT ID, TOUROKU_NO, MAX(START_DATE) AS START_DATE
    FROM TMP1
    GROUP BY ID, TOUROKU_NO
) AS s
INNER JOIN TMP1 AS t
ON s.ID=t.ID AND s.TOUROKU_NO=t.TOUROKU_NO AND s.START_DATE=t.START_DATE
```

あとはこのSQLに対応したLINQを記述します。

```
var tmp1 = TMP1.ToArray();
var normals =
    from s in tmp1
    from e in tmp1
    where s.ID == e.ID && s.TOUROKU_NO == e.TOUROKU_NO && s.START_DATE < e.START_DATE
    select new {
        s.ID,
        s.START_DATE,
        s.TOUROKU_NO,
        s.CD,
        END_DATE = e.START_DATE,
    };
var rests =
    from r in tmp1
    group r.START_DATE by new { r.ID, r.TOUROKU_NO } into g
    join t in tmp1
    on new { g.Key.ID, g.Key.TOUROKU_NO, START_DATE = g.Max() }
    equals new { t.ID, t.TOUROKU_NO, t.START_DATE }
    select new {
        t.ID,
        t.START_DATE,
        t.TOUROKU_NO,
        t.CD,
        END_DATE = DateTime.Now,
    };
var result = normals..Concat(rests);
```

`ToArray()`を外せばDB側で実行できるクエリーを生成してくれることでしょう。

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e031e/3)で書いてみました。pgrhoさんのコードでは7行しか得られておらず、そもそもの問題を解決していません。